# In Rails to manually find_or_create tags. Tags create but id not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a Contacts controller and an update action. I have implemented tagging s.t. it woks fo existing tags. In the instance of a new tag, I want to create it and then add it. I am likely doing this the hard way. Currently, when a new tag is input I get the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Tags with 'id': (3, 6, 1, 0) (found 3 results, but was looking for 4). Couldn't find Tag with id 0.):`

After refreshing the page, I can see the tag now exists and can add it with no error.

Here is my controller update action:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      tagIds = []
      params[:contact][:tag_ids].each do |tagName|
        if tagName != '' && Tag.where(:name => tagName).blank?
            Tag.create!(:name => tagName)
        end
        tagIds.push(Tag.where(:name => tagName).ids)
      end
      puts "contact_params is: #{contact_params}"
      contact_params[:tag_ids] = tagIds
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

contact params returns: `{"name"=>"john smith", "image_url"=>"", "website"=>"", "bio"=>"", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"someone@gail.com", "location_info"=>"", "tag_ids"=>["", "3", "6", "1", "CBD"], "category_ids"=>[""]}`

params is:
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eIwSn9RGzMdds5jrewOvu1VT6ECadlRPCQa6CASQ7VhKgrqVtAYa7FKlVqk5t8IFQVv2b9yA5ruaa0NuT7DxwQ==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"john smith", "phone"=>"", "email"=>"someone@gail.com", "image_url"=>"", "website"=>"", "location_info"=>"", "bio"=>"", "tag_ids"=>["", "3", "6", "1", "CBD"], "category_ids"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Update Contact", "id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Rails way* of doing this would be to use [nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and not by mushing the ids of existing records together with new tags:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, though: :taggings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :contacts, though: :taggings
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

You would create a contact/update with existing and new tags through:

```
Contact.create(
  name: 'Bob',
  tag_ids: [1, 2, 3],
  tags_attributes: [
    { name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }, { name: "baz" }
  ]
)
```

This is not the only way and often not the best solution from a user experience standpoint as they have to submit the form and then find out that the tag already exists and it also makes it easy to create a bunch of duplicates / misspellings.

A good alternative is to use an autocomplete which queries `TagsController#index` to search tags by name as the user types to find existing tags (as seen on Stackoverflow!) together with an ajax call to a separate `TagsController#create` method that creates the tag if it does not exist. You then add the returned id to the list of tags (the `tag_ids` param) by adding an option to the select/checkbox or a hidden input.

This gives the user immediate and useful feedback, keeps the concerns separated on the backend and reduces complexity.

Comment: I'm not going to provide an example here of how to build the ajax approach as it would require a long tutorial. Tagging is a domain thats been done to death though and you should be able to find plenty of tutorials on the web as well as libraries that can do most of the heavy lifting.

Comment: Accepted this answer though I appreciate your other response as well. My earlier solution is terrible as you point out. btw, I know how to do this using a separate front end and api set up, but was trying to use rails monolith for simplicity and I spose i simplified myself too much. I have not found a tutorial using ajax and not involving gem plugins, but I guess I will look for that now. if you happen to have a link. pls share it.  Thanks vm again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to salvage your approach you could do it through:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def update  
    contact_params.merge!(
      separate_tags(params[:contact][:tag_ids])
    )
    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.update(contact_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @contact, notice: 'Contact was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @contact }
      else 
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def separate_tags(ids)
    tags = Tag.where(tag_ids).ids.to_set
    ids, names = tag_ids.separate do |id|
      tags.include?(id)
    end 
    {
      tag_ids: ids,
      tags_attributes: [
        names.map {|name| { name: name }}
      ]
    }
  end
end
```

However it feels like a very hacky approach to use a single array with a mixture of ids and names and YMMV.